# Data Quality Flag

Tags: r, dataframe, data-quality

let's talk about data quality flags. As I have only limited knowledge about this topic, I hope some of you are more experienced.

Let's say we have two tables inside the first layer of a datawarehouse. The first one does contain a `person's ID` and its `DOB`, whereas the second table does hold information about `weight` and `height` in a `key-value` manner and when it was selected.

```
  PersonID DOB                
     <dbl> <dttm>             
1        1 1995-08-10 00:00:00
2        2 1996-02-02 00:00:00
```

and

```
PersonID   Time                type   Value
     <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>  <dbl>
1        1 2000-05-10 00:00:00 weight    55
2        1 2001-05-02 00:00:00 height   172
```

Before I move the data to next layer in the datawarehouse, I want to execute quality checks and add flags that indicate the results of these checks. However, I'm quite confused how to do so. For example,
I can imagine three types of checks

- **column-wise**, e.g. `DOB <= TODAY()`
- **cross-column**, e.g. if `type == weight` then `Value > 0`
- **table-wise**, e.g. `Time > DOB`

So my **first question** is how are these markers usually added? Each quality check in a new table? Code different checks and add the error code of the first failed check in a column? Create a new table to store all failed checks for one row?

The **second question** is about considering the different stages. Suppose the column-wise check of DOB results in RULE_FUTURE_DATE code because the date is in the future. In this case, I can't rely on the `Time > DOB` check in the table-wise stage because we have already identified a problem with one of the columns. How should this be flagged? Another example is, when both column-wise checks finish without error, do I check `DOB < Time` or `Time > DOB` or both?

I would be happy if you could give me a starting point on this topic :-)